# Balancing on two front paws while defecating

Tags: dogs, behavior, defecation

I noticed that when my poodle needs to defecate, he often stands on his two front paws; lifting the rear half of his body upwards toward a tree.  He has done this ever since I've rescued him off the street last year.  I've never seen any other dog exhibit this kind of behavior.

Why would he be doing this?  Is this normal?  Should I be concerned at all?

Comment: Does he only do this when there's a tree around?

Comment: ...your dog does a handstand to poop?

Comment: @JohnCavan:  Not necessarily... he sometimes does it immediately following marking his territory.  Other times he will do it independently of the existence of any sort of pole.

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes.  Is this so odd?

Comment: @Paul I would think it's humorous. I've never heard of such a thing. If he does it while peeing it could be a way to mark his territory as high as he can, but otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: That using of a tree or a pole to balance himself is new to me, but I know a female dog who balances herself on her front paws while peeing. Looks funny, but nothing more to it.

Comment: I used to take care of a toy poodle on occasion and he pooped just like that, though not up against a tree. It was pretty funny to watch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, normal? No, I don't think it is. What it does seem like is possibly [canine obsessive-compulsive disorder](http://www.petmd.com/dog/behavior/evr_dog_behavior_compulsive_disorder#.Ust372RDv48). You mention that he's a rescue from the streets and it's entirely possible that during his street time he reacted or moved into that position during defecation as a result of something happening on the streets and it stuck, it may have even happened more than once.

At any rate, there are many signs of OCD in dogs, and one of them is ritualistic behaviors (*Manual of Clinical Behavioral Medicine for Cats and Dogs*, Dr. Karen L. Overall, page 938) which this seems to fall into. There are behavioral and medicinal treatments for OCD if that is what he has, but you need to get a formal diagnosis and it should be interfering with his day to day life. Having said that, the behavior seems odd, but generally innocuous as you described it and so I don't know that I'd be worried unless it really is preventing him from do his business properly.

Now bear in mind, I'm not a vet nor do I play one on TV. This behavior seemed to have some fit with what I read on canine OCD, ***but this is not a diagnosis*** (sorry, but I feel I should make that clear).

Comment: @Paul - Cheers. Bear in mind, I could be completely wrong, but if nothing else, it's a quirk that you'll remember fondly in the, hopefully, distant future.

Comment: Even if this OCD is what the dog has, I would not worry much, and definitely would not start medicating the dog over such a trivial thing as pooping uphill. (The same was said in the answer too, only not very clearly.)